# Cast a function arguments to a given tuple element types

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates

Is there a simple way to implement a function like this

```
template <typename Tuple, typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_similar_tuple(Args&&... args);
```

that casts its arguments to a given tuple element types preserving CV qualifiers and references and returns a tuple of that arguments.

so that

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<std::string, int>;

make_similar_tuple<Tuple, std::string, int> returns std::tuple<std::string, int>
make_similar_tuple<Tuple, std::string&, int> returns std::tuple<std::string&, int>    
make_similar_tuple<Tuple, std::string&, int8_t> returns std::tuple<std::string&, int>    
make_similar_tuple<Tuple, const char*, int8_t> returns std::tuple<std::string, int>    
make_similar_tuple<Tuple, const std::string&, int> returns std::tuple<const std::string&, int>
```

An example of a user code:

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<std::string, int>;
int i = 10;
auto t = make_similar_tuple<Tuple>("a", i);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), std::tuple<std::string, int&>>);
assert(t == std::make_tuple(std::string("a"), 10));
```

The implementation should cast `"a"` to `std::string` as in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a = static_cast<std::string>("a");

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but the second element remains the reference becuase `i` is `lvalue`.

Comment: It's not clear at all (to me) what is the role of `Tuple` in this example. Please, write an example of code that would use your `make_similar_tuple`.

Comment: @Enlico added an example

Comment: Expecting `std::is_same_v<decltype(t), std::tuple<std::string, int&>>)` is not reasonable, considering that `t.second` is initialized from `i`, which is not an `int` which can be referenced by `int&`. `int& j = i;` doesn't compile indeed. Please, update your request according to this.

Comment: @Enlico yes, that is right, I updated the user code.

Comment: There's other things you need to clarify, imho. For instance, in hindsight, `make_similar_tuple<Tuple, const char*, int8_t>` is at least dubious. You're showing client code relying on TTD to deduce `Args`. Therefore, if you pass a `const char*` lvalue or a literal string (which is an lvalue), you'll get the correspoding element in `Args...` to be a reference. The only way to have it deduced as `const char*`, i.e. non reference, in `Args...`, is that you pass an rvalue `const char*`, e.g. `const char* c{}; make_similar_tuple<Tuple>(std::move(c), int8_t{})`.

Comment: @Enlico yes, there should be `int i = 10;` to `t.second` be a reference. I updated the post.

Comment: I was referring to the second snippet in your question. Please, update that too to match what you actually want, and also please answer my last comment in detail.

Comment: @Enlico Consider this code: `int i = 10; auto t = make_similar_tuple<Tuple>("a", i);`. `t` is of type `std::tuple<std::string, int&>`, because `make_similar_tuple` makes a tuple consisting of a string value (because it constructs it from `char *`) and the reference to `int` (because `i` is lvalue).

Comment: `make_similar_tuple<Tuple>("a", i);` will _**not**_ result in the instantiation of `make_similar_tuple<Tuple, const char*, int>` as part of your second snippet would seem to imply. It will instantiate `make_similar_tuple<Tuple, const char(&)[2], int>`. Please, update _your question_ to address the feedback, so we can clean up these comment section too.

Comment: @Enlico `make_similar_tuple` should cast the arguments, so it does `static_cast<std::string>("a");` that results in `std::string`. This should work with both `const char *` and `const char(&)[2]`, see an example at the bootm of the updated post.

Comment: Note that: `using Tuple = std::tuple<std::string&, int>;` will break all the anwers here since char * -> string & conversion will not occur. I think your requirement is better not be handled for a generic Tuple, but for a decay'd Tuple T.

Comment: @Akash char * -> string & conversion should not occur. If a given tuple element is of type `std::string&` and the corresponding argument is of type `char *` there should be compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can get the corresponding type of the returned `tuple` through [`common_reference_t<T&, Args>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference)

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename Tuple, typename... Args>
constexpr auto
make_similar_tuple(Args&&... args) {
  static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<Tuple> == sizeof...(Args));
  return [&]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::tuple<
      std::common_reference_t<
          std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>&, Args
        >...
    >(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ev94a846e) with your testcases

Comment: It compiles with MSVC, GCC and Android CLang 17

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what std::forward does:

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_similar_tuple(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::tuple<Args&&...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

**update**
the OP is updated to convert string literal to std::string

```
template <class... Types>
constexpr std::tuple< std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<Types>...> 
make_similar_tuple(Types&&... args)
{
    return std::tuple< std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<Types>...>(std::forward<Types>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: what about `make_similar_tuple<Tuple, const char*, int8_t>`?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky you can simply pass `Tuple` as first argument into `make_similar_tuple`

Comment: it is a little bit more complicated, because `char *` becomes `std::string`

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky the updated code should work with your samples. It's actually what `make_tuple` do

Comment: does it produce `std::string` from `char *`?

Comment: yes it does. you can test it with your sample code

Answer (score 0):

Can you implement it in terms of [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)?

> ```cpp
> template< class... Types >
> tuple<Types&&...> forward_as_tuple( Types&&... args ) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Constructs a tuple of references to the arguments in args suitable for forwarding as an argument to a function. The tuple has rvalue reference data members when rvalues are used as arguments, and otherwise has lvalue reference data members.

I think you can do this

```cpp
template <typename Tuple, typename... Args>
constexpr Tuple make_similar_tuple(Args&&... args) {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This way, TTD will work out the `Args...` from the arguments, make a tuple out of them preserving the value categories, and the `return` will cast that tuple to the desired `Tuple`. After all, all you need is that the conversions are possible, as in

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct Foo {
};

struct Bar {
    operator Foo() const;
};

int main() {
    std::tuple<Foo> ti = std::tuple<Bar>{}; // just fine
}
```

[It works in the `char const*` vs `std::string`](https://godbolt.org/z/h4o86b14v) case you mention in a comment:

```cpp
int main() {
    using Tuple = std::tuple<std::string, int>;
    int8_t i = 10;
    auto t = make_similar_tuple<Tuple>("a", i); // LINE
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), Tuple>);
    assert(t == std::make_tuple(std::string("a"), 10));
}
```

Notice that at the `// LINE`, `Args...` is deduced as `[char const(&)[2], signed char&]`, which is correct.

---

As regards the last snippet of code in your question,

> ```cpp
> using Tuple = std::tuple<std::string, int>;
> int8_t i = 10;
> auto t = make_similar_tuple<Tuple>("a", i);
> static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), std::tuple<std::string, int&>>);
> assert(t == std::make_tuple(std::string("a"), 10));
> ```

there's no implementation of `make_similar_tuple` for which it can compile, the reason being that `int8_t` ≠ `int`, so when initializing `t.second`, which is `int` given your desired `make_similar_tuple`, a conversion from `int8_t` (`i`) to `int` (a temporary) is required, and that temporary can't be bound to `int&`.

Comment: what about `make_similar_tuple<Tuple, const char*, int8_t>`?

Comment: `std::forward_as_tuple` can't make `std::string` from `const char *`. The task is not so trivial.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, can you give a look at my update?

Comment: why does it return `Tuple`? what about `make_similar_tuple<Tuple, std::string&, int8_t>`? it should return `std::tuple<std::string&, int>` with it.

Comment: the assert in your code should be `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), std::tuple<std::string, int&>>)`

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky as I said in my comment to your question, that expectation doesn't make sense. You can't have a `int&` to a `int8_t`, i.e. if that `static_assert` passes, then `t.second` can't be bound to the `int8_t` in your code.

Comment: Yes, that is right, I updated the sample of a user code.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, with those edits, [my solution seems to work in this case too](https://godbolt.org/z/Gf8KPzjEv).

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), Tuple>);` is a wrong assert, there should be `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), std::tuple<std::string, int&>>)` as I already mentioned.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, _that casts its arguments to a given tuple element types preserving CV qualifiers and references_. Isn't the given tuple `Tuple`? If so, then how can the cast give back that _and_ the wan you want to assert?

Comment: yes, but the most important assert is `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), std::tuple<std::string, int&>>);`